# Why does `is-hidden` remove element from the dom?

Tags: jquery

Making a toggle for login/logout buttons, but this code seems to remove the element from the dom, or conversely doesn't put it back when I make it active again. The reason I know this is that I have to click my element twice on the page for it to do what it's supposed to. The first time I click it, it works, but on the next "round" of toggles, its length is zero and I get the "prevObject" property in the debugger, so I click it again and it's now in the dom and the length is 1 and we move forward. What am I doing wrong, or not doing?

```js
$('#sz-login-out-group [sz-data-toggle-button]').on('click', (e) => {
  toggleButtonClick($(e.currentTarget));

  const isHidden = 'is-hidden';
  const isActive = 'is-active';
  const logIn = $('#sz-login');
  const logOut = $('#sz-logout');
  const myAccount = $('#sz-my-account');
  const selected = $(e.currentTarget).filter('.is-active');

  if (selected.length) {
    if (selected.prop('id') === 'sz-login') {
      logIn.addClass(isHidden);
      logIn.removeClass(isActive);
      logOut.removeClass(isHidden);
      myAccount.removeClass(isHidden);
      return;
    } else if (selected.prop('id') === 'sz-logout') {
      logIn.removeClass(isHidden);
      logIn.addClass(isActive);
      logOut.addClass(isHidden);
      myAccount.addClass(isHidden);
      return;
    }
  }
});

const toggleButtonClick = (target) => {
  if (target.hasClass('is-active')) {
    target.removeClass('is-active');
    return;
  }
  target.siblings().removeClass('is-active');
  target.addClass('is-active');
};
```

```css
.is-visible {
  display: block !important; }

.is-hidden {
  display: none !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group" id="sz-login-out-group">
  <ul class="menu" data-toggle="menuToggle">
    <li><button class="button primary is-hidden" id="sz-logout" sz-data-toggle-button>Log Out</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear sz-drop" id="sz-login" sz-data-toggle-button>Log In</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear sz-drop is-hidden" id="sz-my-account" sz-data-toggle-button href="">My Account</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear" id="sz-search-bar-toggle" data-toggle="sz-search-bar"><i class="fi-magnifying-glass"></i></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me.

Comment: I did as was suggested, and the behavior is the same as what I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is dramatically more complicated than it needs to be. If we stepped through the code in detail we'd eventually figure out why you're seeing what you're seeing, but fundamentally it's because you're using multiple flags on multiple elements unnecessarily.

Instead:

- Use a single flag class on `#sz-login-out-group`: `logged-in`
- Add it on login, remove it on logout
- Give elements you want only visible when logged-in a class for that, for instance `show-when-logged-in`
- Give elements you want only visible when logged-**out** a class for that, for instance `show-when-logged-out`
- Use CSS rules to show/hide elements based on `.show-when-logged-in` and `.show-when-logged-out` are inside a container with `.logged-in` or not

Example:

```js
$("#sz-login, #sz-logout").on("click", function() {
  $('#sz-login-out-group').toggleClass("logged-in", this.id === "sz-login");
});
```

```css
.show-when-logged-in {
  display: none;
}
.logged-in .show-when-logged-out {
  display: none;
}
.logged-in .show-when-logged-in {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group" id="sz-login-out-group">
  <ul class="menu" data-toggle="menuToggle">
    <li><button class="button primary show-when-logged-in" id="sz-logout">Log Out</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear sz-drop show-when-logged-out" id="sz-login">Log In</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear sz-drop show-when-logged-in" id="sz-my-account" href="">My Account</button></li>
    <li><button class="button clear" id="sz-search-bar-toggle" data-toggle="sz-search-bar"><i class="fi-magnifying-glass"></i></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note I removed the invalid `sz-data-toggle-button` attributes. (If you want to put custom attributes on elements, the `data-` part has to come *first*, e.g., `data-toggle-button`.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to click twice, because on the first time you're removing the `is-active` class, and then you're checking that the class exists via `selected.length` and only then doing work based on that...

```js
const toggleButtonClick = (target) => {
  // first click, remove 'is-active' class, code won't work
  if (target.hasClass('is-active')) {
target.removeClass('is-active');
return;
  }
  // second click, add 'is-active' class, code will work
  target.siblings().removeClass('is-active');
  target.addClass('is-active');
};
```

One possible workaround is to only remove the class after you've done the work like so...

```js
$('#sz-login-out-group [sz-data-toggle-button]').on('click', (e) => {
  toggleButtonClick($(e.currentTarget));

  const isHidden = 'is-hidden';
  const isActive = 'is-active';
  const logIn = $('#sz-login');
  const logOut = $('#sz-logout');
  const myAccount = $('#sz-my-account');
  const selected = $(e.currentTarget).filter('.is-active');

  if (selected.length) {
if (selected.prop('id') === 'sz-login') {
  logIn.addClass(isHidden);
  logIn.removeClass(isActive);
  logOut.removeClass(isHidden);
  myAccount.removeClass(isHidden);
} else if (selected.prop('id') === 'sz-logout') {
  logIn.removeClass(isHidden);
  logIn.addClass(isActive);
  logOut.addClass(isHidden);
  myAccount.addClass(isHidden);
}
  }
  //remove class after the work is done
  if (e.currentTarget.hasClass('is-active')) {
e.currentTarget.removeClass('is-active');
return;
  }
});

const toggleButtonClick = (target) => {
debugger;
  target.siblings().removeClass('is-active');
  target.addClass('is-active');
};
```